# how to avoid a bundled check for key existence and for value True in python

Tags: python, dictionary, key, conditional-statements

I have a dictionary `d` which

- either does not have the key `mykey`
- or `mykey` is present and is a boolean.

I end up with a lot of lines such as:

```
if 'mykey' in d and d['mykey']:
    ...
```

Is there a better way to check this condition to avoid the repetition while accounting for the possible lack of the key in the dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
if dict.get('mykey'):
```

If the key is not present, this returns the default `None`, which is a falsey value. You *could* give it a default value `False`:

```
if dict.get('mykey', False):
```

but that's redundant in this context, really.

Answer (score 2):

```
d.get('mykey', False)
```

This will return `False` if the key is not there, otherwise it will return the actual value corresponding to the key.